# Why uncaught exception when error handler clearly handled the exception in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await

I am trying to understand how nodejs handles the async error handling and have following code https://playcode.io/1579709 with a weird result:

```
function logMsgWithCurrentTime(message) {
  console.log(`${message}--${new Date().getTime()}`);
}

function resolveOrRejectAfter1Seconds(success) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (success) {
        resolve('resolved after 1  ssecond');
      } else {
        reject(new Error('raw ex'));
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  logMsgWithCurrentTime('main calling');
  const asyncP = resolveOrRejectAfter1Seconds(false);
  asyncP
    .then(_ => logMsgWithCurrentTime(_))
    .catch(err => {
      logMsgWithCurrentTime(`Caught err ${err.message}`);
      err.message = 'Sanitized';
    });
  logMsgWithCurrentTime('beforeAwait');
  await asyncP;
  logMsgWithCurrentTime('afterAwait');
  logMsgWithCurrentTime('main done');
}

asyncCall();
```

The program stops at the error handler, but further bubble up a sanitized exception(need to open browser console):
[image]

Why this behavior even we can clearly see the error handler caught and handle the exception by manipulate its message?

If I do the following two things, the program will execute as my expected flow that error handler handles the code and program run to finish:

1. chain the handlers immediately with `asyncP`, like `const asyncP = resolveOrRejectAfter1Seconds(false).then(...).catch(...).
2. Or remove the line of `await asyncP;`

I think these two might related to the first question, but still some explanations would be appreciated.

Thx!

Try the code at https://playcode.io/1579709, remove line 27 `await asyncP` or chain the code form line 19 to line 21.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the reason:

[image]

So the `asyncP` is a promise without error handler so it will still observe uncaught exception. There is still an implicit `asyncP1` handles the exception it observed and modify the content, which also modifies the exception observed by `asyncP`

Using chaining the handlers immediately with asyncP, like `const asyncP = resolveOrRejectAfter1Seconds(false).then(...).catch(...).`, this `ayncP` would include the proper error handling.

remove the line of `await asyncP`, basically started a fire and forgot promise for `asyncP`?